# How to access nested json inside jsx component in react native?

Tags: json, react-native, jsx

I am trying to list the server response , but some mistake is their in my code about accessing nested json..Following is the structure of json

**Updated:**

```
  {
    "child": [],
    "courses": [{
        "data": {
            "name": "Student 1",
            "date_created": 1514610451,
            "total_students": 4,
            "seats": "",
            "start_date": false,
            "categories": [{
                "name": "Subject",
                "slug": "Subject"
            }],
            "intro": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Main Admin",
                "sub": ""
            },
            "menu_order": 0
        },
        "headers": [],
        "status": 200
    }]
  }
```

And my react part is

```
render(){
        return this.state.course.map(course =>
        <Text style={styles.userStyle}>{course.courses.data.map(datas => datas.name)}</Text>
        );
    }
```

Please help me to figure out the mistake.I am getting `this.state.course.map` is not a function.My fetch request is as follows

```
state= {course:[]};
    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('https://www.mywebsite.com/' + this.props.navigation.state.params.id)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => this.setState({course: responseData}))
    }
```

Comment: Your Json structure is invalid. Validate you json structure: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: No i'm getting a valid json..

Comment: Did you check from that link  i had given. Because I am getting as invalid json. Please validate from that link

Comment: Yes. I think you are getting invalid json because i've pasted only few lines from my json response..I will update it.

Comment: I've updated my question now i am getting a valid json ,it was a typo.But how can i access the datas?

Comment: Looks like `this.state.courses` would be the way to access the `courses` member of the JSON structure, not `this.state.course`? Assuming the JSON object is set to `this.state`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would need to show us how `this.state` is set, but if you're doing something like `this.setState(jsonObject)`, the property you are looking for seems to be `this.state.courses`. This would access the array of courses. However, in the subsequent lines you try to access `course.courses`, which suggests you're setting the state like `this.seState({course: jsonObject})` so it's not clear.

I'd say if you fix the first problem, you'll immediately hit another one because it doesn't look like `data` is an array but an object, so trying to call `map` on it is unlikely to do what you want (unless you've been playing with prototypes).

EDIT:

In response to the new info, I recommend the following:

```
    render(){
         if(this.state.course && this.state.course.courses) {
            return this.state.course.courses.map(course =>
            <Text style={styles.userStyle}>{course.data.name}</Text>
            );
        } else {
           return [];
        }
   }
```

Comment: Yes i've updated my question.But i'm not clear what you just said..Is the error is with using map method over the object?

Comment: @NeethuM edited my answer. Yeah, you were calling map on the top level object, not the array of courses inside it.

Comment: well sorry to say none of the above is working..I don't why i'm getting the same error

Comment: Then you've got other problems in your code I think. Check whether course is null, that the response has completed before trying to render etc. There were several problems with your original code, so I'm imagining there are more elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm..yeah 'll check thoroughly..but when i consoled the response i'm getting values in it.